# Facebook SDK returns no error

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-php-sdk

Good day!

So I'm trying out facebook php sdk v4 with my slim framework app, and when I click my login link I'm getting this:

[image]

As you can see, it didn't return any errors.

**My button login link code**

```
<a href="/loginwithfb" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">
<i class="fa fa-facebook-square"></i> 
Login
</a>
```

**My route:**

```
$app->get('/loginwithfb', 'AuthController::fblogin');
```

**My AuthController:**

```
public static function fblogin() {
    $fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
      'app_id' => '{}',
      'app_secret' => '{}',
      'default_graph_version' => 'v2.5',
      //'default_access_token' => '{access-token}', // optional
    ]);

    // Use one of the helper classes to get a Facebook\Authentication\AccessToken entity.
    //   $helper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();
    //   $helper = $fb->getJavaScriptHelper();
    //   $helper = $fb->getCanvasHelper();
    //   $helper = $fb->getPageTabHelper();

    try {
      // Get the Facebook\GraphNodes\GraphUser object for the current user.
      // If you provided a 'default_access_token', the '{access-token}' is optional.
      $response = $fb->get('/me', '{access-token}');
    } catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
      // When Graph returns an error
      echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
      exit;
    } catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
      // When validation fails or other local issues
      echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
      exit;
    }

    $me = $response->getGraphUser();
    echo 'Logged in as ' . $me->getName();
}
```

I installed the facebook php sdk via composer.

Am I missing something here?

Comment: Can you var_dump the whole exception object $e, and see if that shows any additional information?